# Python: Cannot print tuple of 5 lists to file

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am trying to print a tuple of 5 lists to a file in Python, however, I get the error:

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'tuple' object to str implicitly
```

the following is my code:

```
def listjoin():
illegallist = zip(carreglist, illegalspeed, illegaltime, illegalname, illegaladdress)
for item in illegallist:
    illegaldatafile.write("Registration: "+item)
    illegaldatafile.write("\n")
    illegaldatafile.write("Speed "+item)
    illegaldatafile.write("\n")
    illegaldatafile.write("Time: "+item)
    illegaldatafile.write("\n")
    illegaldatafile.write("Name: "+item)
    illegaldatafile.write("\n")
    illegaldatafile.write("Address: "+item)
    illegaldatafile.write("\n")
    illegaldatafile.write("\n")
    illegaldatafile.close()
```

I'm trying to get something like this:

```
Registration: BH34JKX
Speed: 80
Time: 6:45:21
Name: John Adams
Address: SW34 7MN

Registration: DX34JKS
```

etc..
 (Accidentally posted too early)

I printed a list toa file earlier in my code, and it did not need to be converted to a string. I can't do this:

```
illegallist = zip(str(carreglist, illegalspeed, illegaltime, illegalname, illegaladdress))
```

Because str() only takes 3 arguments.
I tried putting it here:

```
illegallist = str(zip(carreglist, illegalspeed, illegaltime, illegalname, illegaladdress))
```

But then It just says that my file is closed.

Comment: 1. You can only write strings to files. 2. Why are you trying to write the exact same object (`item`) on each line and expecting that to produce a different result each time?

Comment: Unpack the list, and if they're not strings cast them.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi: You mean "unpack the _tuples_".

Comment: 1) Python 3's `str` constructor _can_ take up to 3 args, but only the first arg is the object you want to convert to string; the other 2 args relate to the string's encoding, see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) for details. 2) You should not close the file in the `for` loop. Only close it when you've finished writing everything. Even better, use a `with` statement so your file is closed automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of calling each loop iteration's item simply `item`, you should unpack it so you can more easily reference each object. String formatting will also be helpful:

```
def listjoin():
    illegallist = zip(carreglist, illegalspeed, illegaltime, illegalname, illegaladdress)
    for reg,speed,timing,name,address in illegallist:
        illegaldatafile.write("Registration: {}\n".format(reg))
        illegaldatafile.write("Speed: {}\n".format(speed))
        illegaldatafile.write("Time: {}\n".format(timing))
        illegaldatafile.write("Name: {}\n".format(name))
        illegaldatafile.write("Address: {}\n\n".format(address))
    illegaldatafile.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

You are appending the same tuple `item` over and over to a string. You have to take individual elements from this tuple. This is my (more compact) proposal:

```
colnames = ['Registration', 'Speed', 'Time', 'Name', 'Address']
for tup in zip(carreglist, illegalspeed, illegaltime, illegalname, illegaladdress):
    for colname, value in zip(colnames, tup):
        illegaldatafile.write('{}: {}\n'.format(colname, value))
    illegaldatafile.write('\n')
```

Comment: Sorry, but TigerhawkT3's response looks more similar to my own, and I don't want to change it too much.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `print` statement with `file` parameter and if you have only 5 tuples you could use `%`:

```
def listjoin():
    illegallist = zip(carreglist, illegalspeed, illegaltime, illegalname, illegaladdress)
    for item in illegallist:
        print("Registration: %s" % item[0], file=illegaldatafile)
        print("Speed: %s" % item[1], file=illegaldatafile)
        print("Time: %s" % item[2], file=illegaldatafile)
        print("Name: %s" % item[3], file=illegaldatafile)
        print("Address: %s" % item[4], file=illegaldatafile)
        print(file=illegaldatafile)
    illegaldatafile.close()
```